# Java - How to create JavaDocs in Apache Ivy

Tags: java, ant, ivy

I know how to create `javadocs` for my source file in **Apache Ant Build**.

```
 <target name="doc" description="generate documentation">
    <delete dir="${doc.dir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${doc.dir}"/>
    <javadoc sourcepath="${source.dir}" destdir="${doc.dir}"/>
 </target>
```

But I don't know how to create them in **Apache Ivy**.

Could some one show me a sample example ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apache Ivy is a dependency management library for use with (not a replacement for) Apache Ant. Therefore, you will use the same `<javadoc>` task as always.

Comment: But can you show me an example ivy file which has that task written ? I am new to Ivy

Comment: No, you are new to Apache Ant. Ivy is just an external tool / library that can be embedded in an Apache Ant build file. See: http://ant.apache.org/external.html

Comment: @Daemon just use the example you posted in your build.xml. Targets belong into build.xml files. You can't put targets into ivy.xml files (those are just for dependencies)

Answer (score 2):

Apache Ivy is a dependency manager that works with Ant (a  build manager). Apache Ivy is usually (or possible always?) used with Ant to handle builds. Since javadoc creation is a build task not a dependency task, it wouldn't make sense to generate javadocs using Ivy.

Comment: But can you show me an example ivy file which has that task written ? I am new to Ivy

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're going around in a circle here. Ivy works with Ant. You still have a `build.xml` file that you use for your builds. The `ivy.xml` file simply contains a list of the third-party jars your project needs in order to build. Thus, the direct answer to your question would be:

Put the following in your `build.xml`:

```
<target name="doc" description="generate documentation">
    <delete dir="${doc.dir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${doc.dir}"/>
    <javadoc sourcepath="${source.dir}" destdir="${doc.dir}"/>
</target>
```

---

When you use Ivy, you still use Ant. And, you still have a `build.xml` file. And, you still write compose your build with various Ant tasks.

Download [this project](http://seantheflexguy.com/blog/2009/02/25/simple-spring-example-project/). It's a simple build that contains three class files and a `build.xml` file. You will notice there's a jar directory with the following two jars:

- commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
- spring.jar

If you look at lines 36 to 40 of the `build.xml` file, the project is creating a compile classpath like this:

```
 <path id="java">
     <fileset file="jar/spring.jar"/>
     <fileset file="jar/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar"/>
 </path>
```

So, when he compiles, he does this:

```
 <javac destdir="bin">
     <src path="${src}"/>
     <classpath refid="java"/>
 </javac>
```

---

Now, let's look at how this may change with Ivy. In Ivy, I create a `ivy.xml` file that contains a description of what jars I need. However, I only have to specify classes I use directly. In this case, I only need the `spring.jar`. Here's my `ivy.xml`:

```
<ivy-module version="1.0>
     <info organisation="com.seantheflexguy"  
         name="ContextExample"
         revision="1.0"/>

    <configurations>
        <conf="default" visibility="public"/>
        <conf="compile" visibility="public"/>
    </configurations>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring"
            rev="2.0.4"   conf="compile->default"/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

Now, instead, of using the jars in the `jar` directory, I'll have Ivy construct the classpath:

```
 <ivy:resolve/>
 <ivy:cachepath pathid="java"/>

 <javac destdir="bin">
     <src path="${src}"/>
     <classpath refid="java"/>
 </javac>
```

Notice instead of using the `<path>` task to create a classpath, I use two Ant tasks that Ivy uses. The `<ivy:resolve/>` looks at my `ivy.xml` and resolves my dependencies on the jars I request. These jars will be downloaded into my `$HOME/.ivy2/cache` directory.

The `<ivy:cachepath>` task creates a classpath I'm calling the classpath `java` because that's what it was previously called.

With those two Ivy tasks, I've created a classpath that I can use with the `<javac>` task. In fact, I'm not even bothering to change the `<javac>` task.

So, in Ivy:

- I still need my `build.xml`. It's how I define the various build tasks I need to do. In fact, Ivy defines even more Ant tasks I need in my `build.xml` file.
- The `ivy.xml` file simply defines my jar dependencies. When I implement Ivy in this project, I can delete the `jar` directory.

Does this help you understand how Ivy works?